# How to replace backward slash to forward slash using java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm importing a CSV file to MySQL database. This can be done using `java.mysql` support for forward slash in file path. If user gives the path

```
c:\upload\date\csv\sample.csv
```

MySQL doesn't support this type of path pattern. I want to search for backslashes in the path and replace them with a forward slash, to give this:

```
  c:/upload/date/csv/sample.csv
```

How is that done?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In java, use this:

```
str = str.replace("\\", "/");
```

Note that the regex version of replace, ie [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), is not required here; [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) still replaces all occurrences of the search term, but it searches for *literal* Strings, not regex matches.

Comment: how to do reverse operation of the above like str=str.replace("\","//");

Comment: @srinivasgowda if you mean you want to replace forward slashes with backslashes, just swap the parameters: `str = str.replace("/", "\\");`

Comment: No for single backward slash(\) to double forward slash(//)

Comment: @sri `str = str.replace("\\", "//");`

Comment: how to replace it globally

Comment: @Umashankar please read my answer: `replace()` replaces **all** occurrences - ie "globally"

Answer (score 12):

The String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) example provided by @PaulPRO and @Bohemian will work, but its better to use the String.replace(char, char) version. Slightly faster. Though you won't have a noticeable speed difference, its better to do such optimisations where possible.

```
String replacedStr = str.replace('\\', '/');
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have:

`String s = "c:\\upload\\date\\csv\\sample.csv";`

In Java, you can just use:

`s = s.replace("\\", "/");`

Which will make s equal to:

`c:/upload/date/csv/sample.csv`

Comment: You need to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

For double back slash ("\\")

For Java you can use string.replaceAll("\\\\","/")

&

For Kotlin you can use string.replace("\\\\".toRegex(),"/")