# How to replace backslash with forward slash in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, escaping

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805028/how-to-replace-backward-slash-to-forward-slash-using-java), how do I achieve the same in Perl?

I want to convert:

```
C:\Dir1\SubDir1\` to `C:/Dir1/SubDir1/
```

I am trying to follow examples given [here](http://www.htmlite.com/perl025c.php), but when I say something like:

```
my $replacedString= ~s/$dir/"/"; # $dir is C:\Dir1\SubDir1\
```

I get a compilation error. I've tried escaping the `/`, but I then get other compiler errors.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`= ~` is very different from `=~`. The first is assignment and bitwise negation, the second is the binding operator used with regexes.

What you want is this:

```
$string_to_change =~ s/pattern_to_look_for/string_to_replace_with/g;
```

Note the use of the global `/g` option to make changes throughout your string. In your case, looks like you need:

```
$dir =~ s/\\/\//g;
```

If you want a more readable regex, you can exchange the delimiter: `s#\\#/#g;`

If you want to preserve your original string, you can copy it before doing the replacement. You can also use transliteration: `tr#\\#/#` -- in which case you need no global option.

In short:

```
$dir =~ tr#\\#/#;
```

Documentation:

- [Perl operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)
- [Regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 6):

You're splitting the `=~` operator and missing the global modifier.  Just assign `$dir` to `$replacedString` and then do the substitution.

```
my $replacedString = $dir;
$replacedString =~ s|\\|/|g;
```

You can use [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html), the translate operator, instead of the `s` operator too to get simpler code.

```
my $replacedString = $dir;
$replacedString =~ tr|\\|/|;
```

Answer (score 6):

You might actually be looking for [File::Spec->canonpath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aSpec) or [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Path%3a%3aClass) without realizing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
use warnings;    
use strict;    
my $str = 'c:/windows/';    
$str =~ tr{/}{\\};    
print $str;
```

Output:

> c:\windows\